# Change table tr elements using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change a few table cells in a function which I've reduced down to this short snippet, to help me understand what is going wrong.

I basically need to use column indexes on an identified `<tr>` table row and change the value shown in that cell.

I've tried, from looking at various code that accesses table rows,

```
tr.col[1].innerHTML = "NEW NAME";
tr.cell[1].innerHTML = "NEW NAME";
```

Also, I'm currently using jQuery as this is part of an ajax call but this might be complicating things. I'm new to JS and jQuery and don't know which parts are which (I know `var tr = $('#tbl_id_4')` doesn't work without jQuery

```js
function ChangeName(){
    alert('Clicked');
    var tr = $('#tbl_id_4');
    tr[1].innerHTML = "NEW NAME";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="JrmTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tbl_id_1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Peter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tbl_id_4">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Paul</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="ChangeName()" value="Click Me" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the index accessor on the `#tbl_id_4` element. As such you're looking for the second element with that `id`, which obviously does not, and cannot, exist.

To fix this you need to look at the `children()` of the `tr`. Also note the use of an unobtrusive event handler in this example. Inline event attributes are no longer good practice and should be avoided where possible.

```js
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var tr = $('#tbl_id_4');
  tr.children()[1].innerHTML = "NEW NAME";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="JrmTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tbl_id_1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Peter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tbl_id_4">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Paul</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Click Me" />
```

It's also worth noting that as you're already using jQuery, you could just do this:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('#tbl_id_4 td:eq(1)').text("NEW NAME");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="JrmTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tbl_id_1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Peter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tbl_id_4">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Paul</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Click Me" />
```

Comment: Ah ok, so it was the children property I was looking for, I was trying `tr.cells` etc. but this makes sense, thanks!